# mailto behaves abnormally in Safari browser

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser, mailto

I have Safari 5.1.7 installed on my system.I have installed and set default email client Mozilla Thunderbird.

I have an application which has link like

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">email</a>
```

This works fine in Chrome,Opera,IE and Firefox.But does not work in Safari.

How to fix this.I searched on Google for this.There it is suggested that we should set an email client for Safari. But I am unable to set email client for safari.
See the screenshot[image]

I am using windows 7 as Operating system
Using Default Programs setting of windows I have set Thunderbird as default email client.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `mailto` extension in order to achieve that.

See here: https://sites.google.com/site/mailtoextension/

Comment: The link given on the url provided by you is not working

Comment: @Muk Hmm really? It works for me. Try this one https://sites.google.com/site/mailtoextension/mailto.safariextz?attredirects=0

Comment: @mattyommo When i click on "Click here to download your attachment." this error comes "This webpage is not available".

Comment: @Muk Weird, there are a few more download links on Google. Try this one http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/mailto-for-Safari-Download-205107.html

Comment: Is there any other way apart from extension.I am running this safari on windows 7?

Comment: @Muk There is on a Mac (as the other answer shows), but as you're on windows you'll need that extension.

Comment: Please las help.How to install the extension you suggested on  windows safari.I downloaded this.

Comment: @Muk Check out this page for that: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19337/how-to-use-and-manage-extensions-to-safari-5/

Answer (score 0):

You set the default mail client in Mail I believe, or maybe in System Preferences. I don't have a Mac here, so cannot check. In Mail you set Thunderbird as default mail client.

Comment: Neither does the OP. (If you look at the screenshot you'll see the browser is running on Windows.)

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed that!

Comment: Is there any other way apart from extension.I am running this safari on windows 7